# How to control the left and right function of an RC toy car connected to Arduino via Android using Bluetooth in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arduino

I am trying to figure out the coding in [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) for the function to make the [RC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-controlled_model) toy car go left or right with Android as the controller. The car itself is wired to an [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino). I also have no idea on how can I do the Android coding in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) that can make the Arduino read/recognise the button click on the Android device. Here is my code so far for controlling the buttons.

```
    // Connect to Bluetooth Module
    connect_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (connectStat) {
                // Attempt to disconnect from the device
                disconnect();
            }
            else{
                // Attempt to connect to the device
                connect();
            }
        }
    });

    // Toggle Headlights
    led_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ledStat) {
                Arduino = (byte) (Arduino & 124);
                led_button.setText(R.string.ledON);
                ledStat = false;
            }
            else{
                Arduino = (byte) (Arduino | 128);
                led_button.setText(R.string.ledOFF);
                ledStat = true;
            }
            write(Arduino);
        }
    });

    // Drive forward
    forward_button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) |
                (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
                forward_button.setPressed(true);
                Arduino = (byte) (Arduino | 16);
                write(Arduino);
                return true;

            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                forward_button.setPressed(false);
                Arduino = (byte) (Arduino & 236);
                write(Arduino);
                return true;
            }
            forward_button.setPressed(false);
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Back up
    reverse_button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) |
                (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
                reverse_button.setPressed(true);
                Arduino = (byte) (Arduino | 32);
                write(Arduino);
                return true;
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                reverse_button.setPressed(false);
                Arduino = (byte) (Arduino & 220);
                write(Arduino);
                return true;
            }
            reverse_button.setPressed(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

I have nothing on the left and right function, and can I just ask, what does the "Arduino
| 32" in this `Arduino = (byte) (Arduino | 32);` mean? What is the 32 for?

Answer (score 0):

The notation `Arduino | 32` means `Arduino` bitwise or `32` which again means *set bit 6 in the Arduino byte*, for example:

```
Arduino      = 10001010
32           = 00010000

Arduino | 32 = 10011010
```

Similarly `&` is *bitwise and*.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks! So this part of the code connects to the arduino??

Comment: You don't show us the definition of the `connect()`, `disconnect()` and `write( ... )` methods, but I expect they do the setup/teardown and comms with the Arduino board.

Comment: the connect() and disconnect() are just to connect to bluetooth and the write() i suppose that is to write the data on the arduino. The write() i got it from one code i found online.